# Is there a way to redirect www.foo.com/* to foo.com/* using Ruby on Rails without mod_rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, mod-rewrite, heroku

I want to redirect any request from www.foo.com to foo.com.  Normally, I'd use mod_rewrite to do this and just use a regular expression to match any subdomains.  However, I'm using Heroku to host this app which, from what I can tell, doesn't give me this ability.

Is there an easy way in Ruby on Rails to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Same reason bit.ly does this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a before_filter in your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :redirect_www

  def redirect_www
    if /www/.match(request.host)
      redirect_to request.protocol + request.host_with_port + request.request_uri
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to remove www from front of request.host_with_port and while matching need to match only start of the hostname followed by a '.'.

Comment: Though this is a great answer and would work well, I decided to write a middleware hook instead.  I'm not sure what the advantage or disadvantage of this over the before_filter event, however it seemed somehow to be a better place for this code to live.

Comment: No problems, whatever works for you. P.S., just checked out KitchenPC.com. I love the design!

Comment: Thanks!!  That site's all in .NET, I'm a bit more familiar with that platform :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use redirect. Take a look at the redirection here :

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to let me match on the host name, only the document path.